# EC2 Instance working from browser for ~30 minutes, then stops for ~10 minutes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I successfully implemented HTTPS into my Elastic Beanstalk environment today. I route my domain name from NameCheap to Route 53, where it uses an SSL certificate.

Now I am running into a weird issue that I assume is just a simple configuration setting. Both my regular domain and https domain work for around 10 minutes on my browser.

After this, I get an `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` whenever I try to access either. After about 30-40 minutes of this, it then works again for around 10 minutes and this cycle continues.

Strangely enough, it seems to be working more often or maybe differently for my phone browser.

Is this a problem with my DNS, EC2, Elastic Beanstalk, or some other settings?

I am still pretty new to web development and AWS, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could it be an issue with your server-side code? Maybe you're triggering an exception when hitting a certain route and this is causing it to crash

Comment: @itsanewabstract I don't think so because I've been using the same exact URL each time I type it in. It connects for a bit and works great, but the next second it won't connect at all

Comment: It's unlikely that it's a problem with DNS since you are able to connect to the domain at all. When you encounter the error the next time, see if your EC2 instances have stopped running

Comment: @itsanewabstract right now I am unable to connect to the domain and the instance is running and the environment is healthy. I first thought this issue was because I was changing some DNS record settings and it was just taking a while for them to register, but I haven't changed any settings in a couple hours now